# Compact space on ℤ

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, integers, separation-axioms

I want to make $ℤ$ (or equivalently, any countably infinite set) a compact space, as long as it satisfies a separation axiom. What is the maximum possible value of $x$ such that the space satisfies $T_x$ axiom? Could the space be metric, or even completely metric?

(I'm going to make this a challenge to post on Code Golf SE, tbh.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make $\Bbb Z$ a compact space is as follows.  Define $d(z_1,z_2) = |f(z_1) - f(z_2)|$ where
$$
f(z) = \begin{cases}
0 & z=0\\
1/z & z \neq 0.\\
\end{cases}
$$
As far as separation axioms go, the resulting space is at least normal Hausdorff, so $x \geq 4$.

Comment: Do you mean a metric by $d$? Then the space must be perfectly normal Hausdorff, hence $x = 6$.

Comment: @DannyuNDos yes $d$ is a metric.  I didn't know that but I'll take your word for it.